# Only root can mount, why?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

I am dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. I looked at my `/etc/fstab` yesterday and realized it did not contain my Windows 7 partition. So I added it myself, but now it tells me it cannot mount the partition. My `/etc/fstab` now looks like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

# Ubuntu /dev/sda6
UUID=581c89aa-d71c-460c-96c0-04f188fe862a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 1

# swap /dev/sda5
UUID=99b951b9-1a57-43ee-938e-fe31b1ba754f none            swap    sw           $

# Windows /dev/sda3
UUID=12AA9E31AA9E1179         /media/12AA9E31AA9E1179     ntfs    errors=remount-r0 0 2
```

I am trying to mount it by opening a file browser and simply clicking the drive with my mouse. What did I do wrong here when editing my fstab?

Comment: I can post my previous fstab too if anyone thinks it is useful.

Comment: Your windows disk line contains "errors=remount-r0" - mount would probably prefer "o" instead of "0" at the end.

Comment: Oh whoops, thanks for pointing that out. I changed it, but it didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `user` argument to allow regular users to mount the drive. i.e.:

```
UUID=12AA9E31AA9E1179         /media/12AA9E31AA9E1179     ntfs    users,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

This will make it automatically mount at boot. You may also want to check the permissions of the folder that you are mounting to (/media/12AA9E31AA9E1179) when the drive is unmounted and make sure that your other users have access to this folder.

Also, here is some more useful information on [fstab](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html).

If you want to be able to manually mount and unmount the drive from Nautilus, just remove the line altogether, or comment it out with a #. That will leave it up to Nautilus to mount/unmount it, which works better in that case.

Comment: I did that and rebooted. Now the partition is mounting automatically, but I can't unmount it. The error message says only the root can unmount...

Comment: Hmm, I changed that and stopped it from mounting automatically (I don't want it to), but now when I try to mount, it says "Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root." It gives me a link and the link says to do chown root $(which ntfs-3g) and chmod 4755 $(which ntfs-3g)...I'm hesitant to do a chmod though. Does that advice sound like it would help?

Comment: Okay I changed it and now it says "Mount is denied because setuid and setgid root ntfs-3g is insecure with the
external FUSE library. Either remove the setuid/setgid bit from the binary or rebuild NTFS-3G... " This is a noob question I know, but how do I rebuild it now that I have done a chown and chmod?

Comment: I set the noauto argument and that makes it not mount at startup which is what I want. But these errors are happening when I try to mount it any other time.

Comment: Also, when I try chmod 0755 $(which ntfs-3g) it tells me I'm missing an operand after '0755'..? This is separate, but why would it say that?

Comment: Yeah I'm very close to just taking it back out. But I really don't understand why that works. I use cinnamon for my desktop, so what is it doing that I'm not? Currently the line is

UUID=12AA9E31AA9E1179         /media/12AA9E31AA9E1179     ntfs    user,noauto,errors=remount-ro 0 2"    

That makes sense to me. If you see anything wrong in it, please let me know. Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: If you remove it then the mounting is handled by Nautilus/Gnome and uses pmount (I believe). Fstab is really meant to be used for permanent automatic mounts, so with all we know now about your situation, it really doesn't make much sense to use. I'll update my answer and remove all these comments.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to mount the partition from Nautilus (Ubuntu's default file browser) you shouldn't need any entry in /etc/fstab, and it's likely that removing the entry entirely will allow you to mount the partition via nautilus again. If you want to be able to mount the partition from the terminal as your user, you can use the command `udisks --mount /dev/sda3`.

Comment: Why doesn't it need to be in fstab to be mounted though?

Answer (score -1):

Try mounting your NTFS drives in the "**/media**" folder and your *nix drives in the "**/mnt**" folder this should solve your problem :)

FYI, the reason you add entries to the **/etc/fstab** file is so that the system can "automount" them at at boot time, and for convenience i.e. when you use

`$ sudo mount -atO`, (mount all the entries in the fstab file!)

you can, however, just mount/unmount any drive at any time using...

mount -t *type device dir*

umount *dir*

i.e. `$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/Windows7`

and `$ sudo umount /media/Windows7`

Also make sure you create a folder in the "**/media**" folder first to mount the drive i.e.

`$ sudo mkdir /media/Windows7`

Hope this helps.