# How can I get permanent access to an external NAS?

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, backup

New info at the bottom

= = = = =

I've been looking at youtubes and askubuntu pages and other sources for days.

I want to back up files to a WD MyBookLive NAS that I set up under windows.  It's on my wireless home network.  I want to have it occur automatically on a schedule.  I can see the NAS, have a bookmark for *one first-level directory* on it ("Lew" below), and I can copy files to and from it in Files. I can't make a bookmark to the NAS itself.  The permissions on all first-level directories on it are "unknown".

[image: Files output]

I created a directory on it called deja-dup, and I've pointed Backups to "/MyBookLive.local/Lew/deja-dup".  I forget where I got the ".local" syntax.  The directory deja-dup's permissions are drwxrwxrwx.

But Backups says "error creating directory: permission denied".  Also, to get to it in Files I have to enter my system password and the NAS user and password.   "Remember forever" isn't working.  I thought that mounting it might make it available without logging on.

But the information I'm getting varies (pertains to USBs, hard drives on a laptop, wired devices -- but not wireless network NAS), and it's sometimes unclear and in any case I can't even find the NAS.  For example, some discussions start with picking the device from Disks but I can only see my machine's ssd.

[image: results in Disks]

NEW INFO

I couldn't get to the NAS admin page at first because an old FF link to it timed out. Used win10 on my wife's dual boot machine to get the correct ip address.  While I was there I changed its workgroup to WORKGROUP, because one page (11! years old) said that ubuntu expects that value by default.

Now I can get to the WD admin page from ubuntu. It shows shares that I could always see on ubuntu (without the NAS' admin page).

But it still doesn't show up in Disks (see above).  So, a little progress, but not really.

MORE NEW INFO

I was going to post this as an answer, but it's still not working right.

I finally found [this 2014 article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/).  Following the procedures described resulted in the selected file share (Lew) on my NAS unit appearing in Files and on the launchbar.  I was able to point Backups to it and back up my Downloads (small) directory.

The first time I restarted the machine, it took MUCH much longer, including a note that the NAS 'didn't respond for 120 seconds, retrying'.  It finally came up, and the share appears in Files and on the launchbar.

But when I click on them it says that only root can mount the share.  In terminal I entered 'sudo mount -a', and the files are available.  Not how tech should be, but I'm getting closer.

Comment: Can you access this NAS' admin pages? Create an NFS share, add it to your `/etc/fstab` and use it as if it was a normal directory on your system.

Comment: I believe I can get to the admin page.  What's an NFS share?

Comment: network file system. Like I said it would allow you to use your NAS capacity over your network from your PC as if you added an additional HDD

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it seems to be working.

1. got the right **ip address** of the NAS (had to use a windows machine to get to it)
2. changed the **NAS' workgroup** from HOMENETWORK to WORKGROUP -- I forget which post suggested it.
3. followed the **instructions in [this 2014 article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/)** by Ji m. That resulted in the share appearing as described above under MORE NEW INFO. I still had to mount it manually at the terminal with 'sudo mount -a'.
4. changed **permissions** to open up (chmod 777) to [home]/**.smbcredentials** -- I forget which post suggested it.
5. changed **permissions** to open up (chmod 777) to **the share on the NAS** that I mounted in #1 -- I forget which post suggested it.
6. per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178270/only-root-can-mount-why), **added "user" to the 4th element of Ji m's fstab line** (see his step 4):

   his syntax: "... cifs credentials=...."

   my final syntax: "... cifs user,credentials=...."

The machine was taking a LONG time to shut down.  I changed my new **user** to **users**, and it shut down more normally.  The manpage for mount specifies that user allows non-root to mount, but you need user**s** for non-root to unmount.  The machine still takes longer to boot up.

I haven't tested to see whether ##2, 4, and 5 were really needed, but the laptop is at home and no one else uses it, so I'm leaving it as is for now.  I still can't see the NAS in Disks.